# Build plain object with arrays in properties in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this:

```
var items = {};
var id = 'varID';
if (typeof items.id == 'undefined') {
    items.id = {};
}
```

From what I understand, this assigns the empty property `id` to the plain object `items`.

How can I assign the property `varID` to the plain object `items` instead, using the variable `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
items[id] = items[id] || {}; //Does the same work as the if statement
```

instead of `items.id`. With this you can assign **dynamic** properties. 
(Trust me, I had the same problem once.)

Or you can use `Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)` (a little bit different).

Quoting the documentation:

```
The Object.defineProperty() method defines a new property directly on an object 
or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns the object.
```

Check out more in *[Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)*.

These are two ways of doing the trick. Clearly the second one is a little bit different from the first one that is simpler.

Comment: nope, it does not convert it to an `array`.